# How to enable already disabled button without pressing any button?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a button, it is disabled when pressed because each time the button is pressed a script runs (but both the GUI and script run 'simultaneously' because of threading). I want to be able to then have the button enable again after the script finishes running. The problem is that the button is written in a kv file and the function to run the script is written in python.

I've tried to call the instance 'press_b' outside the kv file but to no luck. I've seen cases where people trying calling a button outside the .kv file but then to make any changes the user would have to press another button to re-enable the previous button, I don't want another button.

**.kv**

```
<GUI>:
    GridLayout:
        Button:
            id: press_b
            text: "Press"
            font_size:30
            pos:130,180
            size:150,80
            on_press: root.func.start()
            on_release: press_b.disabled=True
```

**.py**

```py
class GUI(GridLayout):
    def open_script(instance):
        script.run()
        #press_b enable

    #both the script and gui run simultaneosly
    func = threading.Thread(target=open_script, args=(1,))
```

Everytime I would try to call 'press_b' outside the code I would get "NameError: name 'press_b' is not defined"

Comment: Eventlisteners!

Comment: [replying to Joel] I have researched event listeners and I don't think it's what I'm looking for, this is a question asking how to re-enable a button, not how to monitor when a process finishes. If I have got the wrong idea, please expand on your comment.

Comment: You can re-enable it with an eventlistener of your choice. When your script finishes - just call the button. If this is not what you want then you should look at thread schedulers & pools.